# How to suppress some Python errors/warnings in VS Code

Tags: python, ide, visual-studio-code, lint

I have upgraded my VS Code to the latest version, 1.30.0. Then it starts to complain about `unresolved import`. This is because my work uses docker, so docker image contains all the dependencies while my local machine doesn't. I don't want to install all the packages locally. Is there any way I can disable that errors/warnings?

The output looks like warnings, as there is a yellow triangle at the beginning with text like

```
[Python] unresolved import 'freezegun'
```

I have tried to set log level to error, and set `python.analysis.disabled` to `unresolved import`, but nothing works. Probably I did something wrong.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any way to annotate something like this for specific lines or blocks.  I have some imports that are correctly found at runtime because I'm modifying sys.path.  I don't want to ignore all unresolved imports, just the one I know about.

Answer (score 5):

Adding `"python.analysis.disabled": ["unresolved-import"],` in settings solves this.

Answer (score 1):

Above answer didn't work for me because there was no such option `python.analysis.disabled` (vscode version 1.63.2)

#### 1. Solution

Current solution could be found at [this answer (more in depth)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210700/5031366). In short add this to settings.json

```
"python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
    "reportMissingImports": "none"
},
```

---

#### 2. Another Workaround

Another quick workaround is to use [regex filter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-regular-expressions-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) and negate it using `!`
For example: `!import` will show every match that does NOT contain word *import*

[image]

---

#### 3. Using Docker Environment

To address the issue of Docker containing all dependencies, consider using the [Remote - Containers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers) extension by Microsoft. This extension allows you to open projects within a container and use the container's environment.

> The Remote - Containers extension lets you use a Docker container as a full-featured development environment.